# Stacking different HPE switches

Tags: stacking, aruba

Is it possible to stack 1 Aruba 2920-48G (J9728A) with 1 Aruba 2930M-48G (JL321A) each with its proper stacking module ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to say no, running latest firmware on my 2920 (J9728A), the only stacking member options are as follows:

J9729A
 J9727A
 J9728A
 J9726A